# Validating Multiple Dynamically Created Fields

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have a form with dynamically created fields one of which is a file input field.

For non-dynamically created input fields, I use this to validate on the server side:

```
if(isset ($_POST['submitform']))
    {
        $error = array();

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) 
            {
                $data[$key] = filter($value);
            }

        if(empty($data['randominputfield']))
            {
                $error[] = "<p>Input something here</p>";
            }

        $target = "path/to/folder/"; 

        $fileinput = ($_FILES['fileupload']['name']);
        $filebasename = substr($fileinput, 0, strripos($fileinput, '.')); 
        $fileextension  = substr($fileinput, strripos($fileinput, '.'));
        $filesize = $_FILES["fileupload"]["size"];
        $fileformats = array('.png','.jpeg','.jpg','.gif');

        if (in_array($fileextension, $fileformats) && ($filesize <= 350000))
            {
                // Rename file
                $fileinputnewname = md5($filebasename) . $fileextension;
                if (file_exists("path/to/folder/" . $fileinputnewname))
                    {
                        $error[] = "<p>A file with this name already exists</p>";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $filemove = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"], "path/to/folder" . $fileinputnewname);
                    }
            }

        elseif (empty($filebasename))
            {
                $error[] = "<p>Please select a file to upload</p>";
            }

        elseif ($filesize > 350000)
            {
                $error[] = "<p>Files should not exceed 350kB</p>";
            }
        else
            {
                $error[] = "<p>Only files with the extensions ". implode(', ',$fileformats)." are allowed</p>"; 
                unlink($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"]);
            } 


        if(empty($error))
            { 
                //perform database insertion
            }
    }
```

and that works beautifully.

But now I want to give the user the opportunity of adding an infinite number of fields (I accomplished this using jQuery) so that they can upload more than one set of data (i.e. the random input and a file) at the same time and I want to validate and then proceed to store each set of data in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: so loop though the submitted files\names

Comment: @Dagon an example, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this approach for a dynamic number of inputs...

First make your jQuery to append each data set on the form this way:

```
//On each click at the "plus" button append two inputs like these ones
<input name="dynamicFields[fileDescription][]" placeholder="File description..."><br>
<input type="file" name="dynamicFields[file][]">
```

The at server side you'll get in your `$_POST` var two arrays one with the file descriptions and one with the files. You can use this method to group data sets:

```
public static function parseInputTable($inputTable)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($inputTable as $columnName => $columnValues) {
        foreach ($columnValues as $rowIndex => $columnValue) {
            $result[$rowIndex][$columnName] = $columnValue;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

So for example:

```
var_dump(parseInputTable($_POST['dynamicFields']));
```

Outputs

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ['fileDescription'] => string(4) "foo1",
    ['file'] => /*file 1*/
  },
  [1] => array(2) {
    ['fileDescription'] => string(4) "foo2",
    ['file'] => /*file 2*/
  },
  [2] => array(2) {
    ['fileDescription'] => string(4) "foo3",
    ['file'] => /*file 3*/
  }
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand this. I'm trying to validate them and then insert them into a database. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user3754923 I've described how to deal with multiple dynamic fields in a form to parse them in PHP. Now you just need to run a `foreach` in the `parseInputTable` return and validate each data set, then add they to the database only if you found no errors. Got it?